# Mysql not union

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables.

table 1:

```
ID  CUST_NO
1   51555
2   51556
3   51111
4   44444
5   54878
6   13548
```

and table 2:

```
ID  CUST_NO
1   51555
2   51556
3   31333
4   97948
5   65488
6   14648
.   .....
```

I know I can use union to get the CUST_NO's that appear in both tables. However, I need to get the list of CUST_NO's that appear in table 1, but not in table 2.

So a result for this should be

```
51111
44444
54878
13548
```

I bet this is really easy but I just can't use my head right now, any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, nice, three different correct answers in the span of a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t1.CUST_NO
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.CUST_NO = t2.CUST_NO
where t2.CUST_NO is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cust_no
from table1
where not exists
(select cust_no from table2 where table2.cust_no = table1.cust_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `NOT IN` subquery is simplest, though probably not fastest:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  CUST_NO
FROM tab1
WHERE CUST_NO NOT IN (SELECT CUST_NO FROM tab2);
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that this isn't actually the fastest solution, at least in some cases.  It probably depends on the relative sizes of the two tables, and on the presence or absence of indexes.  If table 2 is small, this might be quite efficient; if it is much larger than table 1, and has an index on cust_no, Dippi's solution might be better.  No idea how the left join compares.