# Find values that fail sql join on

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a query such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1
JOIN Table_2
ON Table_1.Col_1 = Table_2.Col_1
```

So I have 100 records and 98 of them are equal so that query would print out 98 out of 100.  How can I get SQL to print the 2 that failed to meet the join?

Comment: isn't that the "<>" operator in the where statement?

Comment: If you do the <> then it will give you every time it fails.  It would take Col_1.Table_1 and check that against every Col_1.Table_2 giving you 98 that are not equal * every row you have so 9,800 not equal instead of 2

Comment: @Yves M. - No, because the records are not in the resulting set.  A different query is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650627/mysql-not-union

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON (Table_1.Col_1 = Table_2.Col_1)
```

The fields of `Table_2` will be NULL where there was no match for the `ON` clause. You'll then be able to add a `WHERE TABLE_2.Col_1 IS NULL` to keep only records in `Table_1` that didn't have a match in `Table_2`.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to the LEFT JOIN is to use EXISTS.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_2 WHERE Col_1 = Table_1.Col_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table_1` LEFT JOIN `Table_2` ON (`Table_1`.`Col_1` = `Table_2`.`Col_1`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS B
ON (A.Col = B.Col)
WHERE B.Col IS NULL
```